# Eclipse Error occurred computing diffs Linux

Tags: eclipse, git

When i try to do commit
Eclipse return this
"Error occurred computing diffs"

**Exception Stack Trace**

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 7
\.idea\
       ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.internal.Strings.convertGlob(Strings.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.internal.WildCardMatcher.<init>(WildCardMatcher.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.internal.PathMatcher.createNameMatcher0(PathMatcher.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.internal.PathMatcher.createPathMatcher(PathMatcher.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.FastIgnoreRule.<init>(FastIgnoreRule.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.ignore.IgnoreNode.parse(IgnoreNode.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator$PerDirectoryIgnoreNode.load(WorkingTreeIterator.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.getIgnoreNode(WorkingTreeIterator.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.isEntryIgnored(WorkingTreeIterator.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.isEntryIgnored(WorkingTreeIterator.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.WorkingTreeIterator.isEntryIgnored(WorkingTreeIterator.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.IndexDiffFilter.include(IndexDiffFilter.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.AndTreeFilter$List.include(AndTreeFilter.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.next(TreeWalk.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.IndexDiff.diff(IndexDiff.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitUI.buildIndexHeadDiffList(CommitUI.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitUI.access$0(CommitUI.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitUI$1.run(CommitUI.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Any idea, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Search the source tree for any ".gitignore" file containing the line ".idea\" and remove the line